# "Command not found" inside shell script

Tags: bash, macos

I have a shell script on a mac (OSX 10.9) named msii810161816_TMP_CMD with the following content.

```
matlab
```

When I execute it, I get

```
./msii810161816_TMP_CMD: line 1: matlab: command not found
```

However, when I type matlab into the shell directly it starts as normal. How can it be that the same command works inside the shell but not inside a shell script? I copy-pasted the command directly from the script into the shell and it worked ...

PS: When I replace the content of the script with

```
echo matlab
```

I get the desired result, so I can definitely execute the shell script (I use ./msii810161816_TMP_CMD)

Thanks guys!

Comment: The shell script is executable (I have executed it with echo matlab). Whats a shebang line? The only content of my file is "matlab"

Comment: If by shebang line, you mean adding #!/bin/sh to the beginning of the script, I just did it but it did not make any difference.

Comment: try to replace matlab by /full/path/to/matlab

Comment: yes that works... for certain reasons I would prefer not to use the full path though ... maybe the problem is that I have defined matlab via alias matlab=".." and not export Path=. Could someone explain the difference?

Comment: Please, provide exact alias string. It's hard to make an answer without context

Comment: If your matlab alias includes the full path or sets PATH then yes, that's the issue.

Comment: alias matlab="/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/matlab"

Comment: Aliases are not expanded in shell scripts; you have to use the full path.

Answer (score 3):

By default, aliases are not expanded in non-interactive shells, which is what shell scripts are. Aliases are intended to be used by a person at the keyboard as a typing aid.

If your goal is to not have to type the full path to `matlab`, instead of creating an alias you should modify your `$PATH`. Add `/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin` to your [`$PATH` environment variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) and then both you and your shell scripts will be able to simply say

```
matlab
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because, as commenters have stated, the `PATH` variable inside of the shell executing the script does not include the directory containing the `matlab` executable.

When a command name is used, like "matlab", your shell looks at every directory in the `PATH` in order, searching for one containing an executable file with the name "matlab".

---

Without going into too much detail, the `PATH` is determined by the shell being invoked.
When you execute `bash`, it combines a global setting for basic directories that must be in the `PATH` with any settings in your `~/.bashrc` which alter the `PATH`.

Most likely, you are not running your script in a shell where the `PATH` includes `matlab`'s directory.
To verify this, you can take the following steps:

- Run `which matlab`. This will show you the path to the matlab executable.
- Run `echo "$PATH"`. This will show you your current `PATH` settings. Note that the directory from `which matlab` is included in the colon-separated list.
- Add a line to the beginning of your script that does `echo "$PATH"`. Note that the directory from `which matlab` is not included.

To resolve this, ensure that your script is executed in a shell that has the needed directory in the `PATH`.
You can do this a few ways, but the two most highly recommended ones would be

1. Add a shebang line to the start of your script. Assuming that you want to run it with `bash`, do `#!/bin/bash` or whatever the path to your bash interpreter is.
   The shebang line is not actually fully standardized by POSIX, so BSD-derived systems like OSX will happily handle multiple arguments to the shebanged executable, while Linux systems pass at most one argument.
   In spite of this, the shebang is an easy and simple way to document what should be used to execute the script, so it's a good solution.
2. Explicitly invoke your script with a shell as its interpreter, as in `bash myscript.sh` or `tcsh myscript.sh` or even `sh myscript.sh`
   This is not incompatible with using a shebang line, and using both is a common practice.
   I believe that the default shell on OSX is always bash, so you should start by trying with that.

---

If these instructions don't help, then you'll have to dig deeper to find out why or how the `PATH` is being altered between the calling context and the script's internal context.
Ultimately, this is almost certainly the source of your issue.

Comment: If using an explicit interpreter, it should always be one that matches the shebang -- if invoking a script written by its author as having a `#!/bin/bash` shebang using `sh`, bash-only language features won't be available, and bugs will often ensue. `tcsh` not being a POSIX-family shell, it's *exceptionally* unlikely to be able to correctly interpret any script that doesn't explicitly have a csh-family shell listed in its shebang line.